# Scrolling to top in RichFaces ModalPanel

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I have a Richfaces ModalPanel having a vertical scroll bar.
Is there a way to scroll to top of this ModalPanel?
I tried to do it with javascript's scroll functions but it didn't work.
Also I tried to focus on the modalpanel's header via javascript's focus function but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i solved the problem.
Bringing the ModalPanel's header text into view by:

```
javascript:document.getElementById('ModalPanelHeaderTextId').scrollIntoView(true);
```

did the trick.